# Why i am getting different locations name while i am at my home?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, core-location, cllocationmanager

I am developing an iOS application to track user movement of the different location. I am using GPS to pull the user location[Alway from the setting location]. it works perfectly, but I am getting different location name while i am in my home.

Like in 1st bedroom you are 1503 location 
and in 2nd bedroom, you are at 1702 location

how these different locations update works in background process?

Comment: Please let me know if there is process of understanding to get different location name in just few meter away

Comment: I think there's a bit of a language barrier here. When you say "1503 location" are you talking about street addresses? So you're taking the user's GPS location and geocoding it, and have found that the street address you get back varies in different rooms?

Comment: Yes, GPS location tracking , but getting different locations in same Home ?

Answer (score 0):

It all depends of the service you are using with CoreLocation. You have [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/getting_the_user_s_location?changes=_5) a list of the different services provided. The Standard location service (tutorial [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/getting_the_user_s_location/using_the_standard_location_service?changes=_5)) will be the most accurate and customizable but the less power friendly. CoreLocation often get you a location then update it to get you more and more precise location, the accuracy will also depends on the quality of your network.

You can customize the Standard location service with the following lines :

```
   locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters
   locationManager.distanceFilter = 100.0  // In meters.
```

Answer (score 0):

The desiredAccuracy is important.

But have you ever notice this? [image]

When you're in a building and have WiFi turned on then CoreLocation uses WiFi to also pinpoint where you are.

**How does identifying a location using WiFi work?**

It's roughly something like this:

Imagine you that your building has 2 sides. Left side (1502) and right side (1702).

The left side has a wifi network named `LeftSideOfBuildingWiFi`

The right side has a wifi network name `RightSideOfBuildingWiFi`

At every moment your locationServices is turned on...Apple will capture the list of WiFi networks. It will say at 1502 the LeftSideOfBuildingWiFi has a stronger signal.

So now some other person enters the house and is connected to `LeftSideOfBuildingWiFi` or has stronger signal with that...Apple will conclude that you're likely at 1502.

This helps preserving the battery of the iOS device. WiFi consumes far less energy than the GPS chip itself.

The same is true if you're in the downtown. Yet if you're in the middle of nowhere in the road then it doesn't apply.

The same *concept* works for significant location services. They use cell-towers rather than GPS chip. Say there are 4 towers near to you and each one has a different signal strength. Likely you're closer to the one which has a stronger signal...

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of error in GPS readings. They get much less accurate when indoors, and can be off by 1000+ meters. Given that much error, it is not at all surprising that the location might geocode to different addresses when you are in different parts of a house.